Interaction armature (animation bvh) with rigid body doesn't work
I build a scene with the following objects (Blender 4.2.3 LTS) :

ground (static)
a sphere figuring the ball(rigid body)
an armature imported from a bvh file (foot shoot)
a rectangular rigid body (figuring the shoe)

I parented the shoe with the foot bone, to make the shoe follow the bone during the movement (this worked).
However, the shoe rigid body doesn't interact correctly with the ball rigid body, it passes through it without deplacing it (see picture)
.
Do you know a way to fix this, or should I give up the idea to make interaction between animations and the rigid body world ?

This question is similar to: Can I make animated body interact with rigid body object. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The suggested solution in this link is to parent the effector object as rigid body to the last bone of the armature, and make it "passive". This is what I did. I create the "foot" as a rectangular mesh as a "passive" rigid bod, and parented it to the foot bone. The ball was a rigid body "active" sphere. Collision were enabled for both objects. Bit it didn't work.

Parent an invisible object to the foot, see my answer below

Create an invisible object (here the wireframe cube) that you parent to 3 vertices of the foot mesh (select the invisible object, shift select the foot, switch to Edit mode, select 3 vertices of the foot, press CtrlP), give a Rigid Body physic to the invisible object, activate its Animated option:

Result:


Thank you very much for your suggestion. However it didn't work. I encounter two problems. 1) Strangely, the vertices parenting work only if I select two vertices (not one, not three...). But with two it works... 2) When I tried to add a rigid body behavior to my invisible cube I get an error message "Rigid Body can't be the child of a non compound Rigid Body". May be it's because my armature animation was loaded from a bvh (motion capture) file.

you must have messed up somewhere, you can't parent to 2 vertices, only one or 3, please share your file with the invisible object

I did nothing particular. Went to edit mode, selected three vertices, ctrl + P but I get an error message "Select one or three vertices...". Tried one vertices, get the same message, and then only two and strangely it worked. You can get the original file here : https://hanneton.org/partage/foot-shoot.blend . Thank you again for the time you spend for this question.

(please consider the "animation" tab in this file,file without the invisible box)

it works fine, apply the scale of all your objects, create a new object that will be you invisible cube, give it Rigid Body, Active and Animated, parent to 3 vertices of Cube, remove the Rigid Body of the current Cube, for the ball remove Collisions, give it Rigid Body? 

Thank you again. A important difference between your file and my file is that my rectangular foot is a static rigid body as yours is not a rigid body. I have one last question : how do you add an invisible box ? As an empty cube (add->empty->cube) ?

don't give any physics to the foot, give it to the invisible object, here it's a cube that i've made it invisble in the Object panel > Viewport Display > Display As > Wire, but you just need to make it invisible in the Outliner (for both viewport and render)

Forget the trouble with parenting vertices, I have mistaken I selected edges. However, I followed precisely your instruction and I didn't encounter any problem. However there is still no collision between the invisible box and the ball. The invisble box is a passive rigid body like in your file. I share the file with the box here : https://hanneton.org/partage/foot-shoot2.blend . I'm afraid this could be a specific problem with motion capture bvh animation.

Unparent the foot and invisible cube with Alt P > Clear and Keep Transformation, close the character's action, reset its location/rotation/scale in Pose mode, move it above the floor, put the foot and invisible cube correctly and parent the foot object back to the foot bone and the invisible cube back to the foot object, apply the scale of all the objects of your scene, create a rotation of the leg so that it hits the ball
